# "Run-Time check failure #2: Stack around the variable 'numbers' was corrupted"

Tags: c, function, pointers

Im writing this little program for a lottery game.

So I got the code to enter my 6 digits and a little function to generate my random numbers, but once Ive entered my 6 numbers and ran a test on my rand Generate function I get an error saying "Run-Time check failure #2: Stack around the variable 'numbers' was corrupted".

Could anyoneof you maybe tell me what Im doing wrong? Im absolutely clueless

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void Generate(int *a){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<= 5;i++){
        a[i] = (1 + (unsigned int)rand()%42);
    }
}

main(){
    int Numbers[5];
    int Lotto[5];
    int i,n;

    for(i = 0; i<=5;i++){
        printf("enter your %de number: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &Numbers[i]);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(n=0; n<6;n++){
        Generate(&Lotto[n]);
        if(n<1){
            printf("%d",Lotto[n]);
        }else{
            printf("%5d",Lotto[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation?

Comment: `int Numbers[5];
                  int Lotto[5];` array size is **5**. `for(i = 0; i<=5;i++){` over index

Comment: If make the array size any bigger it still gives me the error

Comment: @godel9 the indentation?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I changed the Stack sizes to 7 and it still gives me the error

Comment: @user3076306 Never mind. I went ahead and fixed it for you.

Comment: Debugging is so much work, isn't it?  So much easier to get someone else to do it for you.  Have a -1.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
int Numbers[5];
int Lotto[5];

for(n=0; n<6;n++){
    Generate(&Lotto[n]);
```

to

```
int Numbers[6];
int Lotto[6];

Generate(&Lotto[0]);
for(n=0; n<6;n++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong.

```
          for(i = 0; i<=5;i++){
```

It should be

```
          for(i = 0; i<5;i++){
```

as the array `Numbers` has memory only for 5 ints. Same problem with the another loop with `lotto` array and in the function `Generate()` with the pointer access `a`. They are all causing out-of-bounds access error which is [**undefined**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C. Or change the array size accordingly if you want to have 6 integers in them. Remember array indexes start from `0` and go upto `n-1` for an array of size `n`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays are indexed from `0`. You declared both of your arrays of size 5.

Change

```
for(n=0; n<6;n++){...}
```

to

```
for(n=0; n<5;n++){...}
```

otherwise your program's behavior is **undefined**